# overleaf custom biblatex style

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have a custom `biblatex` style from my department that I compile from a `dtx` file using TeX. After compiling it I can include it as a style in the same folder locally, and all works fine.

But I can't get it to work in Overleaf. I can't see any way to compile the `biblatex` style in Overleaf. I've tried uploading all the related files including the `bst` compiled on my machine and it tells me that there is an error in my `.bbx`-file:

```
Package etoolbox Error: \mkdaterangetrunc undefined. See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.383 \renewrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangetrunc}
```

The structure of my Overleaf project, with very little ommitted, is currently as follows. "bath" is the custom biblatex style, "main" is the document and "dissertation_bibliography" is my bibliography:

```
american-bath.lbx
bath.bbx
bath.bst
bath.cbx
bath.dbx
biblatex-bath.bib
biblatex-bath.dtx
biblatex-bath.ins
british-bath.lbx
dissertation_bibliography.bib
main.tex
```

Is this possible? Can I compile it on Overleaf somehow, or will moving the `bst` from my machine work if I do it differently?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by a custom `.bst` file here: `biblatex` uses on a single `.bst`

Comment: @JosephWright Why does it use a `.bst` at all? Is this only for `backend=bibtex`?

Comment: This might be due to a biblatex version mismatch and the style files you're trying to use; Overleaf currently runs the packages in TeX Live 2016 that ships with Ubuntu 16.10 "Yakkety Yak" (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/435-tex-live-upgrade-november-2016). If you want, you can contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, someone will be able to take a look for you.

Comment: @cfr Yes, used by the BibTeX back end to extract data from the `.bib`.

Comment: You should be able to upload the `.bbx`, `.cbx` (and other files such as `.lbx` and `.dbx`) to Overleaf. I'm not sure if you can upload the `.dtx` and compile that, but that you can do once on your machine and then use the resulting files. If the style files are compatible with the version of `biblatex` that Overleaf is running, everything should work out fine. `biblatex` uses only one `.bst` file and that is unlikely to need change, so don't interfere with the `.bst`.

Comment: Without further information we can't really help here. We know neither the structure of your project on overleaf, nor do we know what your custom `biblatex` styles looks like. It would also be interesting to see *how* the compilation fails. What are the warnings/errors?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. Regarding back end I should've mentioned I'm using Biber, in case it changes anything. Also, I'm compiling on Windows so if Overleaf is using Ubuntu could my compiled style not work?

Sorry for not posting the error; I'll add more details to the question above

Comment: This looks as though your style tries to redefine a date macro (`\mkdaterangetrunc`). Date macros have been changed heavily in the last few versions of `biblatex`, so a versions mismatch is very likely. (Either your template is too old, or Overleaf's `biblatex` is too old.) Is there any way we can lay our hands on `bath.bbx` and `bath.cbx` (do the files come from http://www.bath.ac.uk/library/infoskills/referencing-plagiarism/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with an outdated `biblatex` version on Overleaf. Currently Overleaf reports `biblatex 2016/05/14 v3.4` in its logs.

The [Bath bibliography files for `biblatex`](http://www.bath.ac.uk/library/infoskills/referencing-plagiarism/biblatex-bath-v1.0.zip) from http://www.bath.ac.uk/library/infoskills/referencing-plagiarism/, however use recent date commands that have only been introduced in version 3.5.

Until Overleaf update their system to use a `biblatex` version newer than 3.5, you can add the following lines *before* loading `biblatex`

```
\newcommand*{\mkdaterangetrunc}{}
\newcommand*{\mkdaterangetruncextra}{}
\newcommand*{\bibdatetimesep}{}
\newcommand*{\bibtimesep}{}
\newcommand*{\printtime}{}
```

As in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand*{\mkdaterangetrunc}{}
\newcommand*{\mkdaterangetruncextra}{}
\newcommand*{\bibdatetimesep}{}
\newcommand*{\bibtimesep}{}
\newcommand*{\printtime}{}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=bath]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

On Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zcmphqjfgsgv

Note that you will have to live with a few rough edges and possible deviations from the extended output, because `biblatex` 3.4 does not support all the commands used by `bath.bbx`, `bath.cbx`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much moewe. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you use the field `eventdate` in some reference Overleaf will also complain about the command `\dateeraprintpre`. Adding `\newcommand*{\dateeraprintpre}{}` will compile, but the result will have errors in the bibliography.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, defining the missing macros to be empty will only get you so far. You need to wait for Overleaf to update their distribution.