# TeXlive with biblatex - option `dashed' not defined

Tags: biblatex, texlive, ieee-style

I'm creating a beamer presentation that uses `biblatex` with `biber` and the `ieee` style with `dashed=false` to suppress dashing of repeat author names. This compiles find on my MikTeX installation on my laptop, but will not compile on Overleaf.

Further testing on other web-based compilers showed that no TeX live installation recognises the `dashed` option, with any document class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

How can I get `dashed` to work with TeX live?

Comment: It works in texlive 2016 but not in 2015. The web-based compilers are quite often a bit outdated. You would need to get an updated version of the style, but I can't tell you if it would work with an older biblatex.

Comment: Thanks, I feared that would be the case. Looks like there's not much I can do, but I don't use Overleaf too much anyway

Comment: according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357372/overleaf-custom-biblatex-style#comment880278_357372 overleaf uses texlive 2016, but not up-to-date but the one from ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dashed` option was added to `biblatex-ieee` in version 1.2 released 2016-12-26 (with [this commit](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/commit/072144a5e6d505a079b37c89707e036781764083) following [discussion on the bugtracker](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/30)).

Overleaf are currently running `biblatex-ieee` on version 1.1p from 2016-07-20, so that version does not have the `dashed` option. I assume that some other online compilers might be similarly behind with their versions.

If you want to use the `dashed` option with older versions, add

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}
\makeatother
```

and then

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false}
```

to your preamble. (You still can't use `dashed=false` as loading-time option though, because at that moment the option is unknown - it is only defined later in your document.)

On Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/fspxdskjwpsm

Or use one of the solutions offered in [Enabling dashed option for biblatex-ieee style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70411/35864) and [biblatex ieee style same authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/35864).